# WPF MVVM AsyncCommand CanExecute not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, relaycommand

I am attempting to create a simple WPF application that have a combobox populated with server names and a button to connect to a server.

**Expected behaviour:**
Button is disabled at first but become avaiable as soon as a server is selected.

I am using the AsyncCommand [found this in this blog post](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/) that implement the ICommand methods for Async tasks.

My problem is that the button is working properly when using normal RelayCommand but doesnt work when I use AsynCommand. Am I missing something?

Here is the simplified code:

**ConnectionWindow.xaml.cs:**

```xml
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             x:Name="listSourceServer" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ListSourceServer}" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSourceServer}" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="450"        
             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>

<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
            Content="Connect"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="100"
            Height="25"
            FontFamily="Arial"
            Foreground="#FFFFFF"
            Background="#2e86de"
            Command="{Binding ButtonConnectSourceServer}">
    </Button>
```

**ConnectionViewModel.cs:**

```
private string _selectedSourceServer;
public string SelectedSourceServer
    {
        set
        {
            _selectedSourceServer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSourceServer));
        }
        get => _selectedSourceServer;
    }
private async Task ConnectSourceServerAsync()
    {
        await ConnectAsync(SelectedSourceServer);
    }

    private bool CanConnectOnSourceServer()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedSourceServer);
    }

public ConnectionViewModel() { 
    ButtonConnectSourceServer = new AsyncCommand(ConnectSourceServerAsync, CanConnectOnSourceServer);
}
```

**AsyncCommand.cs:**

```
    public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync();
    bool CanExecute();
}

public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<Task> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly IErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public AsyncCommand(
        Func<Task> execute,
        Func<bool> canExecute = null,
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        if (CanExecute())
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                await _execute();
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
            }
        }

        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #region Explicit implementations
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteAsync().FireAndForgetSafeAsync(_errorHandler);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method when the `SelectedSourceServer` property changes.

Comment: I am a bit confused, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method when the `SelectedSourceServer` property changes.

```
public ConnectionViewModel()
{
    _buttonConnectSourceServer = new AsyncCommand(ConnectSourceServerAsync, CanConnectOnSourceServer);
}

private readonly AsyncCommand _buttonConnectSourceServer;
public IAsyncCommand ButtonConnectSourceServer => _buttonConnectSourceServer;

private string _selectedSourceServer;
public string SelectedSourceServer
{
    get => _selectedSourceServer;
    set
    {
        _selectedSourceServer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSourceServer));
        _buttonConnectSourceServer.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```